# SMOOTH Javascript Animations?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have this Javascript animation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fun with animations</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animation.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1 id="x">Hi</h1>
        <h1>Hey</h1>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var header = document.getElementById("header");
    var hHeight = header.style.marginTop | -100;

    header.onclick = move;

    function move() {
        if (hHeight < 0) {
            hHeight += 10;
            header.style.marginTop = hHeight + "px";
            setTimeout(move, 20);
        }

        else if (hHeight >= 0) {
            hHeight -= 10;
            header.style.marginTop = hHeight + "px";
            setTimeout(move, 20);
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, I have a header div. I want the header to slide down and up when clicked. It slides down pretty well, but when it reaches the end it starts glitching out, until you click on it again, which normally stops it. Then when you click on it AGAIN, to bring it back up, it REALLY starts glitching out, and doesn't ever go up or stop.

How do I make a relatively glitch-free script that will produce good animations?

Comment: Is it necessary to hand roll your own animations? Have you checked out the animations provided with jQuery and jQuery UI (depending on what you need)?

Comment: Yes, I have. Apart from me just wanting to learn how to do it myself, there are also some strange technical issues preventing me from using jQuery. No one quite knows what they are, but for some reason neither of my computers can successfully access the jQuery library. It's not my network either - I've tried on multiple networks.

Comment: Can't you download it rather than accessing it over the network ?

Comment: @Tommay When are you expecting your header to stop? Whatever the outcome of your `if()` statement you start the function again, why would it stop? [Slow your timeout down and log your margin to get a better idea of what's going on](http://jsfiddle.net/eu5p9o78/). Also, jQuery is simply a JavaScript file. You can host it locally and reference it.

Comment: I could have downloaded it as well. But like I said, I want to learn Javascript itself and how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As George said, no matter what the condition of hHeight, you are calling move again.  There are a lot of ways to deal with this, here is one:

```js
var header = document.getElementById("header");
var hHeight = header.style.marginTop | -100;

header.onclick = move;

var direction = false;

function moveUp() {
  if (hHeight > -100) {
    hHeight -= 10;
     header.style.marginTop = hHeight + "px";
    setTimeout(moveUp, 20);
  }
}

function moveDown() {
  if (hHeight < 0) {
    hHeight += 10;
     header.style.marginTop = hHeight + "px";
    setTimeout(moveDown, 20);
  }
}

function move() {
  if (direction) {
    setTimeout(moveUp, 20);
  } else {
    setTimeout(moveDown, 20);
  }
  
  direction = !direction;
}
```

```css
#header {
    margin-top: -100px;

}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1 id="x">Hi</h1>
  <h1>Hey</h1>
</div>
```

EDIT: Just use jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a bug. Once the smooth part of the animation is finished, the code keeps running. hHeight is endlessly toggling between 0 and -10 every 20ms.

Your code changes hHeight from -10 to 0:

```
if (hHeight < 0) {
        hHeight += 10;
        ...
```

Then 20ms later, your code changes it from 0 to -10:

```
else if (hHeight >= 0) {
        hHeight -= 10;
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?

```js
 var header = document.getElementById("header");
    var hHeight = header.style.marginTop | -100;

    header.onclick = move;
var timer;
    function move() {
        if (hHeight <=  199) {
            hHeight += 10;
            header.style.marginTop = hHeight + "px";
             timer=setTimeout(move, 20);
        }

        else 
       {
            
            
            setTimeout(moveup, 20);
        }
    }
function moveup(){
  if (hHeight > 0) {
            hHeight -= 10;
            header.style.marginTop = hHeight + "px";
             timer=setTimeout(moveup, 20);
    }else{
      timer=setTimeout(move, 20);}

}
```

```css
#header{background-color:red;}
```

```html
 <button onclick="clearTimeout(timer)">Stop</button><div id="header">
        <h1 id="x">Hi</h1>
        <h1>Hey</h1>
    </div>
```